# Induce vs. induct

Tags: grammar, word-choice

The action of *inducting* (i.e. to induct) someone into something is called *induction*.

The action of *inducing* (i.e. to induce) someone into something is called *inducement*.

In a medical context, why is the process of inducing labour called "induction of labour" rather than "inducement of labour"?

It doesn’t make sense to me linguistically.

Comment: There is no consistency in language patterns, but your medical example is similar to the pattern that you *introduce* with an *introduction* rather than an "*introducement".   (Personally I would have thought the event at the start of a new job would be better described as introduction rather than induction.)

Comment: Because we don't have reduct or conduce and the productive pattern got queered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested explanation, citations needed:

“Induce” is ultimately of Latin origin. The root “duce” often means something to do with “to lead”, like a pattern of movement of going somewhere (like an air “duct”, to intro”duce”, to e”duc”ate, and so on).

One of the verb forms of “duce” is “duct”, which is perfective, meaning, something that was done and has achieved some result. We could imagine that “they’ve been introduced” means the act of introducing occurred, but “they’ve been introducted” could convey that their introducement has resulted in a kind of successful state of affairs in which they are actively involved with each other, bound to each other, or something.

It is a standard Latin pattern for certain verbs to become nouns by switching to the perfective form and then adding the suffix “-ion”. Reduction, reflection, etc.

The suffix “ment” also has Latin origin, and came to English by way of French. However, it is used more freely in English, and has become sort of a productive English suffix in that it is used with non-Latinate words, like “amazement” or “agreement”, though it is also used in Latin with words like “detriment”, “increment” or “implement”.

I would guess “induction” is either an older word or it has more of a technical and scientific connotation or register in English. I know in mathematics people have been talking about “proof by induction” for a while, and probably “induction of a current in a coil” since at least the 1800’s as well. “Inducement” sounds like it was probably an English coinage, taking the Latinate verb “induce”, but not using the perfective nominalization, just adding the general-purpose, basically-English suffix “-ment”.

The result is two words with slightly different connotations and meanings. There’s arguably no “right answer”, though. What is probably an even more distinctively Anglicization of the verb “induce” is the verb “to induct”. Recall that “induct” is a Latin verb form of “*inducere*”, relating to grammatical things like aspect and tense. I think it’s past-perfect. But “induct” at some point became a “productive” English word in that it is used with English verb pattern inflections, like the progressive ending “-ing”, which is English in origin. Thus, “to induct” is sort of like saying “to thrown up” (throw up -> past perfect “have thrown up”). Add “ing” makes it sort of like “thrown upping”.

The point being that humans use determining the rules of their language more than the rules of language determining human use (in a certain way, anyway).

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a better attempt than that - thank you for taking the time.